# First Name and Last name are not visable in admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm using Django-Registration and why the last name and second name is empty in admin panel?If I write all gap and click register and then I go to the admin panel there are username password and email but the first name and last name is empty and I don't know why.

```
lass UserRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
      firstname = forms.CharField(label='First Name',max_length=50)
      lastname = forms.CharField(label='Last Name',max_length=50)
      username = forms.CharField(label='Username',max_length=50)
      email = forms.EmailField()
    password1=forms.CharField(label='Password',max_length=50,min_length=5)
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password',max_length=50,min_length=5)


views.py
def user_registration(request):
form = UserRegistrationForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        firstname = form.cleaned_data['firstname']
        lastname = form.cleaned_data['lastname']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username,email=email, password=password)
        user.firstname = firstname
        user.lastname = lastname
        user.save()
        messages.success(request,'Thaks for registering {} .Enjoy unlimited access to our recipes .'.format(user.username))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:login'))
else:
    form = UserRegistrationForm()   
return render(request,'accounts/register.html',{'form': form})
```

Comment: Can you share your admin.py?

Comment: Can you fix your code formatting? Have you ensured the data in your database actually exists?
Unless you are using a custom user model then the User fields are called `first_name` and `last_name` (notice the underscore), not `firstname` and `lastname`, so you may be setting the wrong attributes in your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `User` model provides `first_name` and `last_name` attributes.
Your should use these attributes while saving the data.

```
def user_registration(request):
form = UserRegistrationForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        firstname = form.cleaned_data['firstname']
        lastname = form.cleaned_data['lastname']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username,email=email, password=password)
        user.first_name = firstname  # use the correct attribute here.
        user.last_name = lastname  # use the correct attribute here.
        user.save()
        messages.success(request,'Thaks for registering {} .Enjoy unlimited access to our recipes .'.format(user.username))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:login'))
else:
    form = UserRegistrationForm()   
return render(request,'accounts/register.html',{'form': form})
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.first_name)

Comment: Yes,you are right .Small mistake but for beginner like me it is not noticeable.Thanks for help.